# AndEngine Level Editor Curve Path

Tags: android, andengine

I wanted to make a curve path in my game (**ANDENGINE**) . Right now i have implemented game like straight line. But my requirement is to run my object into curve path. How may i do this please tell me the way which tool i used  **without using TMX**. Please refer me some another tool or way how may i do this.

[image: Same like this]

Same like this see this image i want to make path like this one. in **ANDENGINE**

Comment: Have you looked at using physics?  Seems to me, it would be easier than trying to devise pathfinding when all you want is a sprite to confirm to the terrain.